# How do you debug a splashscreen image not being found?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor

When I run my app on iPhone 5S, 6, or 6S, the splashscreen appears. When I run on 6 Plus or 6s Plus, I don't see a splashscreen, and I get this in the XCode logs:

`WARNING: The splashscreen image named LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h was not found`

Here is the contents of my `AppRoot/Resources/Images.xcassets`:

[image]

All of the devices and orientations I care about are filled in.

It looks from googling that `LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h` is the default name that XCode looks for when it isn't given an image name. How do I get it to just use the images listed in `Images.xcassets`?

Comment: Not an answer, but it is much easier to use a launch storyboard that simply scales your image

Comment: Thanks, I would, but constrained by the framework I'm using to this style :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Plese see this image]

Fix splashscreen plugin filenames for Asset Catalog.

And use this size of images for Asset Catalog

```
 1: 4.0 inch screen: Default-568h@2x.png
 2: 4.7 inch screen: Default-667h@2x.png
 3: 5.5 inch screen: Default-736h@3x.png
 4: Default.png
```

Comment: I'm not concerned with iOS 5,6 1x (320 x 480), but by the size used for iPhone 6 Plus

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

FWIW, here is what Meteor should configure in file `.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/<App>/Images.xcass‌​ets/LaunchImage.laun‌​chimage/Contents.json`:

```js
{
  "images": [
    {
      "extent": "full-screen",
      "idiom": "iphone",
      "subtype": "736h",
      "filename": "Default-736h.png",
      "minimum-system-version": "8.0",
      "orientation": "portrait",
      "scale": "3x"
    }
    // more...
  ]
}
```

---

Since you seem to use Meteor framework, please note that you can [specify your launch screen files](http://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-launchScreens) in `mobile-config.js`:

```js
App.launchScreens({
  iphone6p_portrait: "path/to/image/from/project/root", // (1242x2208)
  iphone6p_landscape: "path/to/image2/from/project/root" // (2208x1242)
});
```

See the linked reference page for all possible options and expected image sizes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that for portrait, and it's compiled correctly (see top row of image)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Strange indeed, Meteor should automatically configure the `Contents.json` file to point to the appropriate image (in `.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/<App>/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/`)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. My Contents.json looks good. If you're available for hire to help over screenshare, let me know! lorensr+pub@gmail.com

Comment: @Loren thank you for your message! Unfortunately I have not seen that exact issue myself, so I am not sure I could be of big help. By any chance, have you tried deleting the `.meteor/local/cordova-build` folder and let Meteor re-create it on next `meteor run ios`? That usually solves many Cordova related issues.